# drawing graph with math formula in org-mode

Tags: org-babel, images

My goal is to:

1. Generate graph **(with math symbols / equations)** from org-mode source block.
2. Display result inside buffer

My best attempt was to use [dot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_%28graph_description_language%29) and [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/):

[image: graph without math formula]

But I'm unable to add math symbol or equation to the graph. 
Which is, to the best of my knowledge, impossible with [dot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_%28graph_description_language%29). - Please correct me if I'm mistaken.

Whole process inside Emacs looks like this:
[image: work process]

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: If you want to use TeX typesetting, draw the whole thing in TeX.

Comment: How can I draw the whole thing in TeX?

Comment: I'm not the right person to answer that question, but perhaps http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/diagrams/ can get you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the best half-way point between org and LaTeX is unicode. `C-x RET C-\`, set the input method to 'tex', and then you can type `\in` and have it replaced with `∈` in the buffer, no processing needed.

Comment: This is awesome!

Answer (score 2):

For just a few symbols or equations, you can embed latex code with \codes directly in an org file and then use a latex export backend.

For the ultimate in fine-grained layout control, use [dot2texi tool](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/dot2texi) to [wrap dot code](http://www.alessandrovermeulen.me/2013/07/08/combining-graphviz-dot-and-tikz-with-dot2tex/) in latex and then embed that in a [latex source code block](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-LaTeX.html).